# Function notation for an integral

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

Im just reading through my PDE lecture notes and the notation 
 $w(x,t) =\int_{0}^{t}v(x,t;\tau).d\tau$ confuses me, particularly the $t;\tau$ part. What does this mean? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may well replace the ";" with a "," here, that is: $v$ is a function of three variables. There is no qualitative distinction, but I suppose the author wants to distinguish between the variables $x,t$ and the variable $\tau$ because the latter is "more variable" than $x$ and $t$ (which are kept fixed as long as you evaluate the interval for their specific values by letting $\tau$ "run" over $[0,t]$).

Related: Sometimes we use words such as "variable", "parameter", and even "constant" instead of just "variable" throughout merely to emphasize different "levels" of variability, but on a formal level the distinction can totally be ignored ...